# Symfony2 Shell.php error on production server

Tags: symfony

I get the following error in `app_dev.php` on my production server:

> ErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: output in /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Shell/Shell.php line 59
>
> 1. in /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Shell/Shell.php
>      line 59
> 2. at ErrorHandler->handle('8', 'Undefined variable: output', '/www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Shell/Shell.php',
>      '59', array('command' => 'find')) in
>      /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Shell/Shell.php
>      line 59
> 3. at Shell->testCommand('find') in /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Adapter/AbstractFindAdapter.php
>      line 123
> 4. at AbstractFindAdapter->isSupported() in /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Adapter/GnuFindAdapter.php
>      line 30
> 5. at GnuFindAdapter->isSupported() in /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.php
>      line 700
> 6. at Finder->searchInDirectory('/www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Resources/translations')
>      in
>      /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.php
>      line 628
> 7. at Finder->getIterator() in /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php
>      line 555
> 8. at FrameworkExtension->registerTranslatorConfiguration(array('fallback'
>      => 'pl', 'enabled' => true), object(ContainerBuilder)) in /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php
>      line 106
> 9. at FrameworkExtension->load(array(array('translator' => array('fallback' => 'pl'), 'secret' =>
>      'eea6ad638afadb62cd7bc360e98f7d3b', 'router' => array('resource' =>
>      '/www/acme/www/app/config/routing.yml', 'strict_requirements' =>
>      true), 'form' => true, 'csrf_protection' => true, 'validation' =>
>      array('enable_annotations' => true), 'templating' => array('engines'
>      => array('twig')), 'trust_proxy_headers' => false, 'default_locale' => 'pl', 'session' => null), array('router' => array('resource' =>
>      '/www/acme/www/app/config/routing_dev.yml'), 'profiler' =>
>      array('only_exceptions' => false))), object(ContainerBuilder)) in
>      /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php
>      line 42
> 10. at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in
>       /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php
>       line 39
> 11. at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in
>       /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php
>       line 119
> 12. at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php
>       line 494
> 13. at ContainerBuilder->compile() in /www/acme/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 950
> 14. at Kernel->buildContainer() in /www/acme/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 859
> 15. at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /www/acme/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 571
> 16. at Kernel->boot() in /www/acme/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 614
> 17. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /www/acme/www/web/app_dev.php line 29

Everything works fine on my localhost so it can be something wrong with the server configuration.

Comment: Are you running symfony 2.0 or 2.1? Which version of the process component? Which php version? Does the app/check.php and web/config.php point out any errors?

Comment: @Sgoettschkes I have just answered my own question. PHP exec() function is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Hosting provider has turned PHP exec function off because of the security reasons. 
That's why above error occurred.
Does anyone know if its possible to bypass exec function in Symfony2 - I mean if it's possible to run symfony2 on the server with exec function turned off?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem with my hosting, with php safe_mode off. Actually there is a todo, but I dont know when they will fix it.

```
// todo: find a better way (command could not be available)
exec('command -v '.$command, $output, $code);
```

as seen in Symfony\Component\Finder\Shell\Shell;